# Can't convert large CSV file contains data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

how can convert large txt file into mysql database, the file size 3 GB whith 11 million rows.
Each row in the file is like this :

```
"1303179444","","","+20******5811","","","Ahmed","Al Emam","male","/ahmed.e.alemam","","ahmed.e.alemam","Ahmed Al Emam","description here","Ahmed Emam Dental Clinic","Dentist","","Dekernes  Ad Daqahliyah  iraq","MUST","ahmed.e.alemam@ahmed.e.alemam","0","0","0","1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM","1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM","","","","","","","","","",""
```

I tried to separate by comma and enter data to databases via php but it took a very long time and the whole file was not saved. i want another way to convert it to sql file

Comment: @KenLee and use the same method via php? Or is there another better way?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html - is designed for bulk load,

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) command for this task.

First create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    field1 ...,
    field2 ...,
    field3 ...
    PRIMARY KEY (field1)
);
```

Then execute the command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' # full path to the csv file
INTO TABLE items         
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','    # adjust to your csv format
ENCLOSED BY '"'             # adjust to your csv format
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'    # adjust to your csv format
IGNORE 1 ROWS;              # if you have header row in the csv
```

You can also specify the mapping between columns in file and columns in table and even change the.

For example, suppose you want map:

```
[column1 in table] is [column3 in csv]
[column2 in table] is [column5 in csv]
[column3 in table] is [column1 in csv]
[column4 in table] is 2 * [column6 in csv]
[column5 in table] is the current timestamp
ignore [column2 in csv]
ignore [column4 in csv]
```

You can use the command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' # full path to the csv file
INTO TABLE items
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','    # adjust to your csv format
ENCLOSED BY '"'             # adjust to your csv format
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'    # adjust to your csv format
IGNORE 1 ROWS.              # if you have header row in the csv
(column3, @skip, column1, @skip, column2, @c4)
SET 
  column4= 2*@c4, 
  column5=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: There is more than one field that I do not want to add to the databases, how can I ignore it?

Comment: Added example how to map columns in the command

Comment: Excuse me, I tried to understand what you mean, but I don't know, if I have 3 columns in the table they are ` id, name, phone` 
And I have the file like this `"idEcample4546","","","+1621963842","","","Ahmed","Gamal","male","https://www.facebook.com/10","","","James J. Cooper","","","","Mansoura","Mansoura","Mansoura Military Secondary School for Boys المنصورة الثانوية العسكرية بنين","100013005489949@facebook.com","0","0","0","1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM","1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM","","","","","","","","","",""`  and i want only id , name and phone